# Pine Script - How to calculate an average value of the last 5 pivots?

Tags: pivot, pine-script

I want to calculate the average value of the previous pivots, but the problem is, that when I use something like

```
plot(pivothigh(close, 14, 14)[2]) + plot(pivothigh(close, 14, 14)[3]) / 2
```

and then plot the result, it sliding down like if I would just use "highest". 
What I'm trying to do, is calculate the average, and to do so I need to access the exact value of the previous pivots. Can someone help me with that? I'm fighting with it 3 days in a row and when I think it works, I calculating stuff manually and it appears that something is wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `pivothigh(close, 14, 14)[2]` you are not referring to the second pivot back; you are instead referring to the value of the `pivothigh()` function call 2 bars back, where a pivot may or may not have been detected, the proper way to detect that being to test its return value for `na`.

The main problem you need to resolve is how to save the pivot values as they happen, and without arrays in Pine, you will need to code a LIFO queue using n variables, then use `avg()`, which can take up to 10 arguments, to average those variables.

If your pivots can be found without having to look back a too great amount of bars, you could consider using a function like our `avgWhenLast(_src, _cond, _cnt)` in [Averages - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/isSfahiX-Averages-PineCoders-FAQ/#tc3367952).

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any snippet that uses arrays with avgWhenLast that I could reuse? I just never worked with arrays in Pine before. Thank you in advance!